# JQuery function inside JavaScript function :: Processing.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, processing

In the following function, audio is being triggered when user enters his input on a chat. (it is working)

```
 function play_song() {

    var id = Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect(input);
    var aud = document.getElementById(id);
    console.log(id);
    aud.play();

    //(cont)
```

(HTML page)

```
 <form>
 <textarea onfocus="clearContents(this);" id="chat" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
 <button type="button" onclick="play_song();">talk</button>
</form>

<audio id="songName" src="audio/songName.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Inside the same function, I have this JQuery block, to trigger a correspondant animation (creating programatically a processing sketch) for the same song.

```
    //(cont)

    $('#chat').on("onclick", function(event){
          console.log(event);
          var $canvas = $("<canvas>")
         .attr("data-processing-sources", "aud")
         .appendTo("body");
            });
    };
```

(HTML page)

```
<canvas data-processing-sources="sketches/songName.pde"></canvas>
```

I think processing sketches are `attributes`, but I'm not sure.

**QUESTIONS**:

How do I pass the `var` `aud` to the `JQuery` function?

Is using one single function both for audio and animation the most efficient way of achieving my goal?

Comment: change `"aud"` the string to `aud` the variable?

Comment: @Mathletics nothing happens... `$canvas not defined`

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a pretty roundabout way to affect your Processing sketch from JavaScript. You can just write JavaScript that calls your Processing code directly.

[The Processing.js reference](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#mixingjsandprocessing) has an example that does exactly that:

> Reaching out from the Processing code to JavaScript is easier than
>   going the other way, since the JavaScript created by the Processing.js
>   parser is not exposed directly on the global object. Instead, you gain
>   access using the Processing.instances property.
>
> The Processing constructor keeps track of instances it creates, and
>   makes them available using the getInstanceById() method. By default,
>   when a  has a data-processing-sources attribute, its id is
>   used as a unique identifier for the Processing instance. If no id
>   attribute is provided, you can use Processing.instances[0].
>
> After you have a reference to the appropriate Processing instance, you
>   can call into it like so:
>
> ```
>  <!DOCTYPE html>
>  <html>
>  <head>
>      <title>Hello Web - Controlling Processing from JavaScript</title>
>      <script src="processing-1.3.6.min.js"></script>
>  </head>
>  <body>
>      <canvas id="sketch" data-processing-sources="controlling.pde"></canvas>
>      <button onclick="startSketch();">
>          Start</button>
>      <button onclick="stopSketch();">
>          Stop</button>
>      <script type="application/javascript">
>          var processingInstance;
>
>          function startSketch() {
>              switchSketchState(true);
>          }
>
>          function stopSketch() {
>              switchSketchState(false);
>          }
>
>          function switchSketchState(on) {
>              if (!processingInstance) {
>                  processingInstance = Processing.getInstanceById('sketch');
>              }
>
>              if (on) {
>                  processingInstance.loop();  // call Processing loop() nction
>              } else {
>                  processingInstance.noLoop(); // stop animation, call noLoop()
>              }
>          }
>      </script>
>  </body>
>  </html>
> ```
>
> Here two buttons in the DOM are used to allow the user to start or
>   stop a running Processing sketch. They control the Processing instance
>   (you might have several in a page, or hidden in divs) directly from
>   JavaScript, calling Processing functions: loop() and noLoop(). The
>   Processing functions are well documented elsewhere.